# Swift FAILURE: type Mismatch(Swift.Array<Any>)

Tags: json, swift, model

Is there anyone can help me fix my model? It seems it does not match with the JSON from API Response.

JSON response from postman

```
{
 "error_code": 0,
 "data": [
    {
        "kode": "001",
        "name": "BANK INDONESIA PUSAT JAKARTA"
    },
    {
        "kode": "002",
        "name": "PT. BANK RAKYAT INDONESIA (Persero) Tbk."
    },
    {
        "kode": "003",
        "name": "BANK EKSPOR INDONESIA"
    }
],
 "msg": "OK"
}
```

Last Model Edited:

```
struct ObjectBank: Codable {

 let errorCode: Int
 let data: [Bank]
 let msg: String

 enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
    case errorCode = "error_code" , data , msg
 }
}

struct Bank: Codable {
  let kode: String
  let name: String
}
```

[Still got error like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/148Cu.png)

Store model using alamofire

```
    private static func performRequest<T:Decodable>(route:APIRouter, 
     decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder(), completion:@escaping 
      (Result<T>)->Void) -> DataRequest {
    //        Alamofire.request(route).responseJSON {
    //            response in
   //            print(response)
    //        }
    return Alamofire.request(route).responseJSONDecodable (decoder: 
       decoder){ (response: DataResponse<T>) in
            //print(response)
            completion(response.result)
      }
    }
```

Comment: FYI - there's no need for CodingKeys when the property names match the key names.

Comment: this is the JSON response i've got when i print on the console  SUCCESS: {
    data =     (
                {
            kode = 001;
            name = "BANK INDONESIA PUSAT JAKARTA";
        },
                {
            kode = 002;
            name = "PT. BANK RAKYAT INDONESIA (Persero) Tbk.";
        },
                {
            kode = 003;
            name = "BANK EKSPOR INDONESIA";
        },
                {
            kode = 008;
            name = "BANK MANDIRI (PERSERO)";
        }
    );
    "error_code" = 0;
    msg = ok;
}

Comment: then it's successfully parsed

Comment: Do not post details in comments. [Edit] your question as needed.

Comment: upss, sory,, it's my firstime :)

Comment: The JSON you posted in a comment does not match the JSON you posted in your question. Please [edit] your question as needed so your question contains the real JSON.

Comment: And please do not post pictures of text. Copy and paste the error message into your question as text. Images can't be referenced or searched and they are harder to read.

Comment: You are making your question worse with every edit. Please fix your question by including your actual JSON and by replacing the error image with the error text.

Comment: that was the actual JSON from the postman,, is there any help ?

Answer (score 0):

`data` is an array not dictionary

```
let data:[Bank]
```

//

```
struct ObjectBank: Codable {

    let errorCode: Int
    let data: [Bank]
    let msg: String

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case errorCode = "error_code" , data , msg
    }
}

struct Bank: Codable {
    let kode: String
    let name: String
}
```

//

```
do {
    let dic = try JSONDecoder().decode(ObjectBank.self,data)
  }
 catch {
   print(error)
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, this' is what i've got when change the 'data'  to an array https://ibb.co/cO3eyo

Comment: when using this with alamofire .  return Alamofire.request(route).responseJSONDecodable (decoder: decoder){ (response: DataResponse<T>) in
                //print(response)
                completion(response.result)
        }

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your response is ok in principle which you can see using the following Playground:

```
import Cocoa

let jsonData = """
{
 "error_code": 0,
 "data": [
    {
        "kode": "001",
        "name": "BANK INDONESIA PUSAT JAKARTA"
    },
    {
        "kode": "002",
        "name": "PT. BANK RAKYAT INDONESIA (Persero) Tbk."
    },
    {
        "kode": "003",
        "name": "BANK EKSPOR INDONESIA"
    }
],
 "msg": "OK"
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct ObjectBank: Codable {

    let errorCode: Int
    let data: [Bank]
    let msg: String

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case errorCode = "error_code" , data , msg
    }
}

struct Bank: Codable {
    let kode: String
    let name: String
}

do {
    let banks = try JSONDecoder().decode(ObjectBank.self, from: jsonData)
    print(banks)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

This will parse without error. Since I do not know AlamoFire very well I have to assume that there is something going wrong with the type of your `completion` closure. It will "somehow" have to guess that you want to parse `ObjectBank` in order to make any sense of your response.

Maybe you would have an easier time with `responseData`?